# Mapping list of locations to a another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I've been wanted to learn postgis/postgres so I decided to make a simple web app that stores information about sightseeing tours. Now i've hit a bit a of a roadblock on how to actually go about mapping multiple sightseeing locations to a a specific tour entry so I'd figure i'd float this by you guys first.

Little background on how the App works:

Right now I have a table for tours. Each tour will contain basic information like name, cost, dates, and other things. Now with postgis I added a second table to represent "locations" which would represent important location points the tour will pass by. The location table will have a (geometry(Point, 4326)) column to represent the geographic coordinates of the location.

Now this is where I get stuck. A tour will have multiple locations associated with it, and a Location can be part of multiple tours. How would I go about making this relationship? Also If I needed to also store the order in which we'll see locations in a tour how would i go about adding that functionality

Answer (score 1):

Its a n-n relation. So you need a table that store the relation between Tour and Location

Lets call it TourLocation table. It should contain below columns :

```
tourid_int, location_id
```

So when you query to get multiple locations from tour you will do like below

```
select location_id from TourLocation  where tour_id = @tour_id
```

The same thing with location

```
select tour_id from TourLocation  where location_id = @location_id
```

Incase you need locations order when in a tour, just create another table call location_orders that should contains

```
tour_id, locations
```

with locations will store location in order depends on tour_id

Comment: I don't quite understand the location_orders table. How does it store the order of the locations for a tour?

Comment: Locations can be string to store multiple location follow orders, you can store location name or id, and you can store like ('europe_tour', 'london, milan, paris') or u can use id.